# Replace dot character once entered by a comma in jquery

Tags: jquery, keyup

I need to replace dot character on entered by the user by the comma .
I wrote this code but it doesn't give the hopped result

```
$(".dot").keyup(function (event) {

     val = $(this).val();
     length = val.length;
     if (event.key == '.') {
         event.stopPropagation();
         $(this).val(val.substring(0, length)+",");
     }
 });
```

Comment: this `replace dot character on entered by the user by the comma` is not very clear for me :(

Comment: once the user write a dot character it must be replaced by the comme charachter ; is it clear ?

Comment: did you try my solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

have you tried using the string method replace?

```
var res = str.replace(".", ",");
```

Comment: glad to help! :)

Comment: @EnriqueDev, your code is not replacing a dot with a comma it does the opposit

Answer (score 3):

```
Please try this.
```

```js
$('input[type = "text"]').on("keyup", function (e) {
  var val = $(this).val();
    var str=val.replace('.',',');
    $(this).val(str);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='text' id='txtVal' />
```